# Attaching public access policy to an S3 bucket via boto3 "MalformedPolicy error" keeps rearing its head

Tags: amazon-web-services

```
import boto3
import json

S3API = boto3.client("s3", region_name="regionname") 
bucket_name = "bucketname"

policy_file = open("../public_policy.json", "r")


S3API.put_bucket_policy(
    Bucket = 'bucket_name',
    Policy = 'policy_file.read()'
)


botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your policy is **literal string** `"policy_file.read()"`. It should be (assuming the policy file is correct):

```
S3API.put_bucket_policy(
    Bucket = bucket_name,
    Policy = policy_file.read()
)
```